# ajax form with partial view with a dynamically generated list updating values on another partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ajax.beginform

I fairly new to MVC and Razor (Yes, shame on me), 
I have a page with 2 partial views and 1 ajax form with one of the partial view with a dynamically generated list updating values (and failing) to the other partial view, by design it shows the first message of the list.

The problem is when I press a button on one of the items of the list ("Ver" in "_ListaMensajes"), instead of showing the details of the message at the bottom of the page (_detalleMensaje), It do nothing (no calls at controller, or anything)

I followed several tutorials and working projects to do this and it got me confused, I don't know anymore if this code makes sense, please, a little help.

Thanks

PD: I'm using MVC 5.1 (according nuget console)
and referencing: jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult DetalleMensaje(int Id_Mensaje) {
        V_Sedd_Mensaje oV_Sedd_Mensaje = oI_V_Sedd_Mensaje.Recuperar_V_Sedd_Mensaje_PorCodigo(Id_Mensaje);
        return PartialView("_DetalleMensaje", oV_Sedd_Mensaje);
    }
```

page:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <fieldset class="dhhBorder">
        <legend class="dhhBorder">Lista de Envíos</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">Evento</div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Descripcion)</div>

                <div class="col-lg-1">Fecha Envio</div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Fecha_Envio_Short)</div>

                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <button type="button" title="Editar" data-url="/Envios/VerCuadros?Id_Envio_Empresa=@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id_Envio_Empresa)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs modalMTC"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DetalleMensaje", "Envios", new { @id = "FormCabecera" },
                        new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "SeccionMensaje"
                        }))
                {
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <fieldset class="dhhBorder">
                            <legend class="dhhBorder">Lista de Envíos</legend>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12" id="SeccionListado">
                                    @Html.Partial("_ListaMensajes", @Model.lV_Sedd_Mensaje)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                }

                <div class="col-md-10" id="SeccionMensaje">
                    @Html.Partial("_DetalleMensaje", Model.oV_Sedd_Mensaje)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

_ListaMensajes:

```
@using aseDGRAIC.Helpers
@model List<beDGRAIC.V_Sedd_Mensaje>


<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead class="small">
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th class="text-center col-lg-1" scope="col">Orden</th>
                <th class="text-center col-lg-2" scope="col">Tipo</th>
                <th class="text-center col-lg-4" scope="col">Asunto</th>
                <th class="text-center col-lg-1" scope="col">Adjunto</th>
                <th class="text-center col-lg-2" scope="col">Fecha / Hora</th>
                <th class="text-center col-lg-2" scope="col">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                var cuenta = 1;
                foreach (var x in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">@cuenta</td>
                        <td>@x.Tipo</td>
                        <td>@x.Asunto</td>
                        @if (x.Existen_Adjuntos != 0) { 
                            <td><button type="button" title="Editar" data-url="/Envios/VerAdjuntos?Id_Mensaje=@x.Id_Mensaje" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span></button></td>
                        } else { 
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        }
                        <td>@x.Fecha</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" title="Ver" data-url="/Envios/DetalleMensaje?Id_Mensaje=@x.Id_Mensaje" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and _detalleMensaje:

```
@model beDGRAIC.V_Sedd_Mensaje

<div class="panel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row form-horizontal">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label small">Asunto:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @if (Model.Id_Mensaje != 0)
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Asunto, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @disabled = "disabled" })
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Asunto, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-horizontal">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label small">Mensaje:</label><br />
                        <div class="col-md-9">                            
                            @if (Model.Id_Mensaje != 0)
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Mensaje, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @disabled = "disabled" })
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Mensaje, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="btn-group">
        @if (Model.Id_Mensaje == 0) { 
            <button id="btnGrabar" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Enviar</button>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Made some changes on the code based on the comments below, but behaves the same

Comment: Is there a way that an error in my layout is interferring with the jquery? In: `$(window).on('load', function () {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();  <--- here

            if (globalLog == '0') {
                $('.toggleButtonMenu').click();
            }
        });` I got: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Tried with a different layout without errors and behaves the same way...

Comment: You have an ajax form but no submit button. Your partial inside the form (`_ListaMensajes`) does not render any controls so nothing would be submitted anyway. And you loop is generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes`). Then your second partial `_detalleMensaje` which does have some controls is outside the form so its not clear what your actually trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you for your observations, I'll explain what i'm trying to do On _ListaMensajes, is used only to select the message to show (when the button "Ver" is pressed -I guess it has to become submit-) on _DetalleMensaje partialview.
With the second partial, I asumed that the controls will be populated with the passing of the model from the controller method, that is referenced on the Ajax form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that an Ajax.ActionLink is the right control to submit information from an Ajax.Form. So my "_ListaMensajes" partial view submit button change to this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Ver", "DetalleMensaje", new { Id_Mensaje = x.Id_Mensaje }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "SeccionMensaje" })
```

It was hard for me to find any references to this, that's why my delay.

Thanks to Stephen for pointing it out.